# Servlet 3.0 odd declarative security behavior

Tags: jsf-2, servlet-3.0

I have a security constraint declared in web.xml:

```
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>LoggedIn</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/screens/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

After logging in, when I make a GET request against the application I get the expected behavior e.g.

`https://localhost:8443/Patrac/screens/user.xhtml` --> results in access denied.

However, when I do a postback e.g.

`<rich:menuItem submitMode="ajax" label="User" action="/screens/user"/>`

I can view the screen.  If I do a second identical postback, I get the access denied message.  Each time I submit a postback the result alternates between displaying the screen and issuing a 403.  The URL displayed in the browser alternates between the following:

`https://localhost:8443/Patrac/screens/user.xhtml` --> browser URL when access denied

`https://localhost:8443/Patrac/public/403.xhtml` --> browser URL when user screen is  displayed

I understand the way the displayed browser URL in JSF lags behind the screen that is currently displayed, so that's no mystery.  But I don't understand how I'm able to view the screen every other time the same postback is submitted.  Again, GET requests are always denied.

**EDIT :**

I did try post-redirect-get and that made the strange behavior go away, as expected.

```
<rich:menuItem submitMode="ajax" label="User" action="/screens/user?faces-redirect=true"/>
```

However, I don't want to do PRG every time and besides PRG doesn't eliminate the security problem.

What am I missing here?  Thanks for any insights!

Comment: So at first you are accessing a resource in public directory and then doing a forward to screens and as expected it won't restrict that. But after that did you try to view the same view again I mean /public/ -> /screens/user.xhtml --> /screens/user.xhtml

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter whether I first view a screen in /public or not.  If I try to view any of the screens under /screens (e.g. /screens/xxxx.xhtml) via postback I get the alternating behavior described above (back and forth between showing the screen and then issuing a 403).  When I submit a GET the alternating behavior goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security constraint isn't checked on forwards, but on requests. This is by design.

So you definitely need the PRG pattern or, better, normal GET links. It'll instantly also make your webapp more SEO friendly and better bookmarkable. Using POST for page-to-page navigation is bad design anyway.

The "alternating behaviour" you're seeing is because the forward isn't checked, but any subsequent (postback) request on the same page is a fullworthy request and thus checked.

Comment: Thanks, I will use GET links.  However, does this mean that even if I use GET links my web application will be exploitable by a client who issues a POST, which would take advantage of the forward not being checked?  Because the security constraint isn't checked on forwards should I not rely solely on declarative security to prevent unauthorized access to pages?

Comment: Only if you use POST for page-to-page navigation which is a bad practice anyway.